# Document not Updating inside loop

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

The update function is not working inside loop containing array of selected options. Without loop it is working and i have checked that array contains correct values.

Html Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <select multiple class="form-control" id="studentcontainer">

     </select>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    db.collection('Parent').get().then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {

            var data = '<option value="' + doc.data().uid + '">' + doc.data().student_name + " - " + doc.data().student_admno + '</option>';
            document.getElementById('studentcontainer').innerHTML += data;

        });

    });
```

`

```
function assignStudent() {
        var e = document.getElementById("driverscontainer");
        var driverid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + "";
        var selectedElement = document.getElementById('studentcontainer');
        var selectedOptions = selectedElement.selectedOptions || [].filter.call(selectedElement.options, option => option.selected);
        var selectedValues = [].map.call(selectedOptions, option => option.value);
        for (index = 0; index < selectedValues.length; index++) {
            console.log(selectedValues[index]);
            var studentdriver = {
                did : driverid,
                sid : selectedValues[index]
            }
            db.collection("AssignedStudents").doc(driverid).set(studentdriver).then(function() {
            alert("Student Assigned Successfully");
        });
            var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("Parent").doc(selectedValues[index]).update({
                isAssigned: true
            });

        }

        alert("Students Assigned Successfully");

    }
```

Comment: Could you please include the corresponding HTML that will allow us to run your code? Please include only what is [needed to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and strip out unnecessary parts wherever possible.

Comment: Added the HTML code that will contain the details fetched from Firestore.

Comment: And what is not working about it? What is it doing when inside the loop that's different from when it's outside the loop? Add some `console.log` statements for every variable inside your loop and see how they change (or not) with each iteration.

Comment: `studentdriver` is having correct expected values in each iteration but just the `update` statement is not updating the firestore document. For a single selection select field in html, the code is working fine but for multiple selections, i stored all the selected values in an array and executed the update statement for each selected item but it is not working.

Comment: Are there synchronous versions of Firestore operations? If so, try using `async` and `await` to hold up the loop until the storage operation is complete. Alternatively, switch `var studentdriver` to `let studentdriver` to scope the object to the loop iteration.